# visual studio 2015 c++ http get&post

Tags: c++, http-get

I need help with http get. I use vsc++ 2015. I have my own code, but it seems to be wrong, so I get reply from server in a strange format.
Example : 034a0686bc29ca826dbb2f1ea4dd1879═

so the Source is:

```
#include "Connection.h"

CConnector g_pConnector;


CConnector::CConnector() {

}


CConnector::~CConnector() {

}

void CConnector::Connect(char* Url, char* Host) {   m_Url = Url;    m_Host = Host; }

void CConnector::SendPOST(const char* data, std::string &sDestBuffer) {     try {       char httpUseragent[512];        DWORD szhttpUserAgent = sizeof(httpUseragent);      ObtainUserAgentString(0, httpUseragent, &szhttpUserAgent);

        CString sMsg = "";      sMsg += /*\r\ncontent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded*/"\r\ncontent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";       sMsg += /*\r\ncontent-lenght:
*/"\r\ncontent-lenght: ";       sMsg += std::to_string(strlen(data)).c_str();       sMsg += /*\r\nuser-agent: secret_agent\r\n\r\n*/"\r\nuser-agent: secret_agent\r\n\r\n";

        HINTERNET internet = InternetOpenA(httpUseragent, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);         if (internet != NULL)       {

            HINTERNET connect = InternetConnectA(internet, m_Host, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);            if (connect != NULL)            {

                HINTERNET request = HttpOpenRequestA(connect, /*POST*/"POST", m_Url, /*HTTP/1.1*/"HTTP/1.1", NULL, NULL,
                    INTERNET_FLAG_HYPERLINK | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTP |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, NULL);

                if (request != NULL)
                {
                    int datalen = 0;
                    if (data != NULL) datalen = strlen(data);
                    int headerlen = 0;
                    if (!sMsg.IsEmpty()) headerlen = strlen(sMsg);


                    HttpSendRequestA(request, sMsg, headerlen, _strdup(data), datalen);

                    if (request)
                    {
                        DWORD dataSize = 0;
                        DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
                        DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
                        char* data = NULL;
                        do {

                            char buffer[2000];
                            InternetReadFile(request, (LPVOID)buffer, _countof(buffer), &dwBytesRead);
                            char *tempData = new char[dataSize + dwBytesRead];
                            memcpy(tempData, data, dataSize);
                            memcpy(tempData + dataSize, buffer, dwBytesRead);
                            delete[] data;
                            data = tempData;
                            dataSize += dwBytesRead;
                        } while (dwBytesRead);

                        sDestBuffer = data;

                    }

                    InternetCloseHandle(request);
                }           }           InternetCloseHandle(connect);       }       InternetCloseHandle(internet);  }   catch (...) {} }

void CConnector::SendGET(const char* data, std::string &sDestBuffer) {  try {       char httpUseragent[512];        DWORD szhttpUserAgent = sizeof(httpUseragent);      ObtainUserAgentString(0, httpUseragent, &szhttpUserAgent);

        CString sMsg = "";      CString Url = m_Url;        Url += "?";         Url += data;


        HINTERNET internet = InternetOpenA(httpUseragent, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);         if (internet != NULL)       {

            HINTERNET connect = InternetConnectA(internet, m_Host, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);            if (connect != NULL)            {

                HINTERNET request = HttpOpenRequestA(connect, /*GET*/"GET", Url, /*HTTP/1.1*/"HTTP/1.1", NULL, NULL,
                    INTERNET_FLAG_HYPERLINK | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTP |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE |
                    INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, NULL);

                if (request != NULL)
                {
                    int datalen = 0;
                    if (data != NULL) datalen = strlen(data);
                    int headerlen = 0;
                    if (!sMsg.IsEmpty()) headerlen = strlen(sMsg);


                    HttpSendRequestA(request, sMsg, headerlen, _strdup(data), datalen);

                    if (request)
                    {
                        DWORD dataSize = 0;
                        DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
                        DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
                        char* data = NULL;
                        do {

                            char buffer[2000];
                            InternetReadFile(request, (LPVOID)buffer, _countof(buffer), &dwBytesRead);
                            char *tempData = new char[dataSize + dwBytesRead];
                            memcpy(tempData, data, dataSize);
                            memcpy(tempData + dataSize, buffer, dwBytesRead);
                            delete[] data;
                            data = tempData;
                            dataSize += dwBytesRead;
                        } while (dwBytesRead);

                        sDestBuffer = data;

                    }

                    InternetCloseHandle(request);
                }           }           InternetCloseHandle(connect);       }

    InternetCloseHandle(internet);  }   catch (...) {} }
```

and I try getting reply like this

```
std::string request;
char key[128];
g_pConnector.Connect(script.php?something=139, "sample.com");
g_pConnector.SendGET(key, request);
```

Comment: Just someting I noticed: You are using `_strdup` to get a non-const copy of a `const char*` buffer (`data` here) to pass to `HttpOpenRequestA`.  `strdup` uses `malloc` to allocate memory for the buffer it returns, so you should `free` it after use -- but this code just loses the pointer and never `free`s it.  This isn't what's causing you problem though, good luck.